# How to solve "Extra junk at end of file" when using apt?

Tags: apt

I'm trying to configure some proxies for a guest virtual machine and now I'm getting:

```
sudo apt-get update
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxy:4: Extra junk at end of file
```

The content of the file is:

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/95proxy 

Acquire::http::proxy  "http://10.0.0.60:3128/"
Acquire::ftp::proxy "http://10.0.0.60:3128/"
Acquire::https::proxy "http://10.0.0.60:3128/"
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't setting up the end of line semicolons for the configuration file. It should look like this:

```
Acquire::http::proxy  "http://10.0.0.60:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "http://10.0.0.60:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "http://10.0.0.60:3128/";
```

Reading the man page:

> Each line is of the form `APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";`. The quotation marks and **trailing semicolon are required**.

In case of multiple lines using scopes with *curly braces* it should looks:

```
APT {
  Get {
    Assume-Yes "true";
    Fix-Broken "true";
  };
};
```

Comment: "curly brakes"?  Surely you mean "wiggly parentheses"

Comment: @joeytwiddle I meant hammered parentheses, but then it wouldn't make sense...

Comment: This can also happen if you use "single quote" instead of "double quote". Just happened to me.

Comment: You mean, "single quote", instead of 'double quote'?

Comment: @TrippKinetics the manual just says "quotation marks", which includes both. I presume that both are legal.

Comment: @Braiam It was a joke.  (Perhaps a poor one.)  Look at the way I use quotes in the comment.  :)

Comment: Also note that there should be double quote!