# How can I get a 'verbose' apt-get exit code?

Tags: apt

How can I get a 'verbose' exit code for `apt-get` so that errors like this

```
Package google-chrome is a virtual package provided by:
  google-chrome-stable 29.0.1547.76-r223446
  google-chrome-beta 30.0.1599.47-1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'google-chrome' has no installation candidate
```

have a different exit code than download errors like this

```
Err http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main google-chrome-stable amd64 29.0.1547.76-r223446
  Something wicked happened resolving 'dl.google.com:http' (-11 - System error)
```

Currently, both errors exit with `100`

Basically, I'd like to have download errors exit with a different code than errors like the first. If possible, I'd like each specific error to have a different exit code, but the above example is the minimum I need. How can I do this in a vanilla Ubuntu install without additional software (with the exception of `aptitude`)?

Comment: You could wrap the apt-get command in a script that parses the output. Or does that count as "additional software"? Also, to detect download errors, consider doing `apt-get --download-only` first.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Perhaps you could verify the existence of package X first by doing `apt-cache policy X`?

Comment: Again, you would need to grep the output. I assume that doing `apt-cache policy google-chrome` does not give you a line with the word "Candidate", whereas `apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable` would.

Comment: OK. I'm moving this discussion to chat and entering this suggestion as a (partial) answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10673/discussion-between-jos-and-minerz029)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but you could test for the existence of packages first by doing `apt-cache policy X` and grepping the output for "Candidate (none)" or "Couldn't find package X", etc.

Comment: Upvoted for now, but as you said, it's partial. Feel free to delete all your comments that it's in an answer now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 20):

I believe this is not a case of XY, and you just want to be able to debug apt-get generally speaking. Under such assumptions here is my answer.

From the `man apt.conf`:

> ### DEBUG OPTIONS
>
> Enabling options in the Debug:: section will cause debugging information to be sent to the standard
>          error stream of the program utilizing the apt libraries, or enable special program modes that are
>          primarily useful for debugging the behavior of apt.

Hence, you only need to activate the rules for each of the debugging behaviors of `apt-get`:

- **Debug::pkgProblemResolver**: enables output about the decisions made by dist-upgrade, upgrade,
         install, remove, purge.
- **Debug::NoLocking**: disables all file locking. This can be used to run some operations (for instance,
         apt-get -s install) as a non-root user.
- **Debug::pkgDPkgPM**: prints out the actual command line each time that apt invokes dpkg(1).

Those 3 are the first that the man page recommends, and the first will help you to debug the first error you show. For the second you may need:

- **Debug::Acquire::http**: Print information related to downloading packages using HTTP. There is also `https`, `ftp`, `cdrom`.

The man page has many more, you can list them easily using `man apt.conf | grep -A5 -i debug`.

All this should be written [using the correct syntax](https://askubuntu.com/a/342180/169736) and they are accept boolean values:

```
Debug::*::*  "true";
```

or if you want to use multiple lines:

```
Debug {
  Acquire {
    http "true";
    ftp "true";
  };
  NoLocking "true";
};
```

If you want to run for only for a instance of apt-get you can use the `-o`/`--option` switch:

```
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true -o Debug::Acquire::http=true -f install
```

Another method is creating your personalized configuration file and load it with the `-c`/`--config-file` switch:

```
sudo apt-get -c debug-apt.conf install hello
```

About changing the exit codes, I believe you can not unless you change the source code. `apt-get` is a *state of art* piece of software, as such it has advanced methods to debug the process without the need of relying of exit codes.

Comment: I'm actually trying to put these commands in a script which can run unattended. How would I use this in a bash script to find if the first error occurred?

Comment: I'd also like to do this only for a specific instance of `apt-get`, not all the time.

Comment: @minerz029 you can use the `-o` option to run ad-hoc commands. Updated my answer.

Comment: About first comment, you should do something clever with parsing the output. I don't have the sightless idea how can you do that.

Comment: I actually got it to work with grepping the output of `apt-cache policy PACKAGE`, as Jos said. I was trying to check if a package was installable, I may not have asked my question right but this is a good answer

Comment: @minerz029 I doubt his answer help you debugging the "wicked" error, through. And seems that was indeed a case of XY in which your objective didn't match your approach. :(

Comment: Is there any possibility to just turn ALL debugging logging on? ``-o 'Debug::*::*=true' `` doesn't make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig it isn't meant to be a valid configuration, just showing that all configurations under Debug follow a pattern and that all possible options only allow boolean values. Check the examples/configure-index.gz file for all possible options.