# proxy authentication

Tags: apt

I am very new to ubuntu, I decided to try it out two days ago. I am using proxy server [172.31.100.15 with user name and password]. I cant access any on-line resources both with the terminal, transmission(to download torrents), or Ubuntu software center. For firefox, I have configured it and can download .deb and other files but need direct access. Please give me step by step instruction as to how to configure and authenticate 12.04 terminal. Thank you

Comment: It seems you have configured your proxy just in Firefox. You should instead configure it for your whole system: **System Settings → Network → Network proxy**.

Comment: You could try the easy to use GUI tool [GrrProxy](https://github.com/Cadogan/GrrProxy)

Answer (score 0):

Configure your proxy first by System Settings → Network → Network proxy.
Put in 172.31.100.15 and your port there.

After that, open apt.conf

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

You will see

> Acquire::http::proxy "http://172.31.100.15:port/";
>   Acquire::https::proxy "https://172.31.100.15:port/";
>   Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://172.31.100.15:port/";
>   Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://172.31.100.15:port/";

Change it to

> Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@172.31.100.15:port/";
>   Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@172.31.100.15:port/";
>   Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@172.31.100.15:port/";
>   Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:password@172.31.100.15:port/";

Comment: This didn't work for me, but this answer did: http://askubuntu.com/questions/342179/how-to-solve-extra-junk-at-end-of-file-when-using-apt