# How to solve "Extra junk at end of file" syntax error in "01autoremove-kernels" file? // invalid characters

Tags: apt

I've read [How to solve "Extra junk at end of file" when using apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342179/how-to-solve-extra-junk-at-end-of-file-when-using-apt) and though it's a similar problem, it apparently has a different cause since, looking at the contents of the file, unlike in the earlier Q&A it seems far from obvious that adding apostrophes could solve the issue.

[image]

[image]

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click
>   menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. The error message
>   was: 'Unknown Error: '' (E: Syntax
>   error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels:1: Extra junk at end of
>   file)'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet
>   dependencies.

Contents of problematic `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels` (please note, however, that `gedit` complains about **invalid characters**):

```
 ../../../linux-headers-3.2.0-65/scripts/kconfig/streamline_config.pl\00\00\00\0‌​0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\.............‌​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a [solution](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/einfahrtsverbotsschild/3/) which also worked for me:

```
sudo /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal
```

which will first return the above error yet again and secondly and crucially cleanly **re-write the problematic file**, to be finished off by [something](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade) along [the lines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade) of

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

Contents of problematic `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels`

- **before** applying the above mentioned "recovery":

> ```
> ../../../linux-headers-3.2.0-65/scripts/kconfig/streamline_config.pl\00\00\00\0‌​0\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\.............‌​
> ```

- **after** applying the above mentioned "recovery":

> ```
> // File autogenerated by /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal, do not edit
>     APT
>     {
>       NeverAutoRemove
>       {
>         "^linux-image-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>         "^linux-image-extra-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>         "^linux-signed-image-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>         "^linux-backports-modules-.*-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>         "^linux-headers-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>         "^linux-tools-3.2.0-65-generic$";
>       };
>     };
> ```