# Installing MPICH2 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02 prox:2: Extra junk at end of file
```

I want to installing mpich2 on my Ubuntu 16.04. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Feel free to add the content of that file to your question. Might be easier to tell you want to remove that way.

Comment: Does this question and answer help: http://askubuntu.com/q/342179/57576 ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "extra junk at end of file".

See the directory `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`  and a file starting with `02` (I am not sure if `prox:2` is part of the file name).

Use an editor like `nano` or `vi` to open the file and remove the malformed text that seems to be at the end of the file.