# APT behind auth-proxy "Extra junk at end of file" error

Tags: apt, proxy

I am trying to update my Ubuntu desktop "Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS" via APT behind corporate proxy but getting the following issue:

```
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:3: Extra junk at end of file
```

and here is my `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
Acquire::http::proxy “http://usr:pass@10.20.x.x:8080/”;
Acquire::https::proxy “http://usr:pass@10.20.x.x:8080/”;
```

I have tried to search the same on Ask Ubuntu and found [How to solve "Extra junk at end of file" when using apt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/342179) but this doesn't resolve the issue as I am already using the `;` and still facing the same issue.

What should I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ok this issue was with 'double quotations mark' I was using i.e `“` instead of 'quotation mark' i.e `"`.

Changing from `“` to `"` resolved my issue.